# Problem with colorbox reloading the iframe content on colorbox.resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, colorbox

I'm using colorbox (jquery plug-in) to display a multi-step sign-up process. I'm using colorbox in "iframe" mode.

```
$('#signup').colorbox({
    width:     '500px', 
    height:    '250px', 
    opacity:   '.5',
    scrolling: false,
    fixed:     true,
    iframe:    true
});
```

Since the content of the different steps have different heights, I would like for colorbox to resize itself automatically when it loads a new step.

I use the following code in the iframe content (simply in a script tag near the end of the document):

```
$(function() {
    var iH = $(document.body).height();
    console.log("iframe height: " + iH);
    parent.$.colorbox.resize('height', iH);
});
```

Before that I had tried a simpler version:

```
parent.$.colorbox.resize();
```

But in both cases I end up with what seems to be an infinite loop: the content of the iframe is endlessly reloaded and never actually displayed (I can actually see it blink sometimes).
The iframe is resized in the process (during the first loop), so it seems to be partially working. However the new size appears to be too small for the intended content, so I don't really know...

Any idea why this doesn't work and how to solve this?

**Update:**
If I put the above script (simple version) on the second step and not on the first, I avoid the infinite loop, **but** when I click to go to the second step, the first step is actually loaded instead of the second step.
Same goes if I put this script on the third step: the first step is loaded instead.
So it seems that when executing its "resize" function, colorbox kind of restarts it all from the beginning?...

Comment: What happens if you set initialWidth and initialHeight instead of height and width with no subsequent call to resize?

Comment: btw are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @chim: I kinda gave up, but I'm still curious to solve this. I hadn't thought about using initialHeight instead of height. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: After several tests, it seems that the problem is related to the fact I use colorbox in iframe mode. In this mode, neither initialWidth/initialHeigh nor maxWidth/maxHeight seem to work properly (they always open an iframe with a size close to zero). So my guess is that the resize function isn't meant to work in iframe mode either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution here: http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/fadc3d68ca764de3/c38fa24136a6abd7?pli=1

Added this to the colorbox.js (ColorBox v1.3.17.2, right before publicMethod.resize on r 533):

```
publicMethod.myResize = function (iW, iH) { 
 if (!open) {
    return;
 }
 if (settings.scrolling) {
    return;
    }
 var speed = settings.transition === "none" ? 0 : settings.speed;
 $window.unbind('resize.' + prefix);
 settings.w = iW;
 settings.h = iH;
 $loaded.css({
    width: settings.w,
    height: settings.h
 });
 publicMethod.position(speed);
};
```

and I added this to the page opening in the iframe:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $(window).bind('load', function () {
        var frameWidth = $(document).width();
        var frameHeight = $(document).height();
        parent.$.fn.colorbox.myResize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    });
 });
```

To bind the colorbox function i used this options:

```
$('.item').colorbox({
    transition: 'none',
    iframe      : true,
    scrolling   : false
});
```

Comment: That seems to be working, thank you very much! One problem though: it seems to only resize the popup if its content is bigger than the previous content --not if it's smaller (in which case it doesn't resize). Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm not really sure, sorry. For the project i was working on Colorbox required so much alterations that i ultimately decided to build a lightbox from scratch myself.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. I've given up myself for this problem (for various reasons). Thanks anyway for your help!